# Ebay developer API function get_item_aspects_for_category returns only English content

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm working on eBay Developer API with [addItem method](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/additem.html), that requires to make an additional [call](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/Product/Concepts/MakingACall.html) for [category aspects by given category ID](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/commerce/taxonomy/resources/category_tree/methods/getItemAspectsForCategory). My marketplace is `Germany` and `addItem` requires me to send aspects with **German language** but eBay `get_item_aspects_for_category` returns only **English values**. I'm sending `Accept-Language` header as `de-DE` and `X-EBAY-C-MARKETPLACE-ID` as `EBAY_DE` for sure.
What im doing wrong?
For example i have a category id `258017`, that returns something like that:

```
{"aspects":[{"localizedAspectName":"Brand","aspectConstraint":{"aspectDataType":"STRING","itemToAspectCardinality":"SINGLE","aspectMode":"FREE_TEXT","aspectRequired":true,"aspectUsage":"RECOMMENDED","aspectEnabledForVariations":false,"aspectApplicableTo":["PRODUCT"]},"aspectValues":[{"localizedValue":"Unbranded"},{"localizedValue":"+ONE"},{"localizedValue":"10 Strawberry Street"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPD. Yes (not recommended)**, content returns in English, but eBay Developer API has [Translation API](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/commerce/translation/overview.html) with [translate method](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/commerce/translation/resources/language/methods/translate) that works with Deutsch (German) language also and its possible to translate some strings there and then send it to API.

**UPD2. Finally Solved**. `getItemAspectsForCategory` has an URI Parameter named `category_tree_id` that in real is [Ebay Site ID](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/Product/CallRef/Enums/GlobalIdList.html) of needle MarketPlace. But in docs description of this field doesnt follow `site id` implementation.

For example, endpoint for `EBAY_DE` (**site id** `77`) for category `258017` has to be:

`https://api.ebay.com/commerce/taxonomy/v1/category_tree/77/get_item_aspects_for_category?category_id=258017`

Comment: hmm.. do not think `Translation API` is the solution: the name of the fields starts with **localized** that has a clear meaning, furthermore in the documentation it is written **The localized name of this aspect (for example: Colour on the eBay UK site). Note: This name is always localized for the specified marketplace.**
Are you sure POST Header has the right format? usually problem is there

Comment: yes, i made an update/solution

Comment: Great!
I see eBay is planning to mess up the new APIs too!